# Census County Commuter Flow Data?

Tags: data-request, us-census

I've been banging my head on this, and I'm just not having a lot of luck.

I've been using the Census' [American Fact Finder](http://factfinder2.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t) to try and find it, but I'm not seeing it.

What I need is to be able to look at a county (say Cole County, MO) and see where the residents are commuting to for work.

The best I've come up with is [this press kit](http://www.census.gov/newsroom/releases/archives/news_conferences/commuting.html) that has 2006-2010 data, but I also need the data from 2000 and 1990, and I'm just not finding it.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Comment: the press kit you've cited uses the `JWMNP` variable in the [2011 acs codebook](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/Downloads/data_documentation/pums/DataDict/PUMSDataDict11.pdf).. and just bases everything on travel time (not dest. cty codes). the acs didn't get big enough for county-specific estimates until 2005.  you can work with the acs microdata by following [these step-by-step instructions](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20community%20survey%20%28acs%29) but i think you want to use the actual census.  maybe [start here](http://mcdc.missouri.edu/data/workflow/Reports/index.shtml)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a link to county to county commuting flows:

http://www.census.gov/population/metro/data/other.html

For older data, you can take a look at the raw files from:

The 1990 Census: http://www.census.gov/population/www/socdemo/jtw_workerflow.html

The 2000 Census: http://www.census.gov/population/www/cen2000/commuting/index.html

Comment: Um ... that looks to just have the 2006-2010 data ... is there something in there that's poorly labeled that has the earlier data?

Comment: I added some older links to 1990 and 2000 census data

Answer (score 4):

Also look at the Longitudinal Employer Household Dynamics (LEHD) dataset. This is a collaborative Census/BLS effort that links employment and individual records for analysis of labor markets. Data is available at sub-tract geographies, and includes counts of employed people by place of work and residence, and allows for the analysis of journey to work info.  http://lehd.ces.census.gov/ They maintain a tool ("On the Map" - link on the LEHD site) that can be used to query the data and produce reports. It's great stuff.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you would get County to County flow from the LED tool.  I've used On The Map, and it's commuting flow tool is perfect, but it doesn't go back past 2002.

Comment: The Federal DOT maintains these files. ACS-based data is here: http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/planning/census_issues/ctpp/ They archive the data online for 1990 and 2000. http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/planning/census_issues/ctpp/data_products/